# prerequisites needed when moving from angular 1 to angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Currently I'm using `Angular V-1.3`.I heard that `Angular 2` is a way more different than `Angular 1` in terms of usage and implementation.

The concept of scope,directives and other features have been removed and follows a OO model of programming.

So while migrating to Angular 2 do I need to know the concepts of typescript/OOP's. Or what are the prerequisites needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 2 is a complete re-write from Angular 1.x.
[Here](https://twitter.com/toddmotto/status/598277678295347200) is a funny take on that.

As to prerequisites
**1. Do I need to know typescript?**
it is *nice* to learn Typescript, as Angular 2.0 is being written in Typescript. But at the same time, you can write *your application code* in ES 5 or vanilla ES 6. It does not matter as typescript transpiles to ES.
**2. Do I need to know OOP?**
I don't see any reason why not to master OOP as a working / professional / hobby programmer.

If you are looking for a complete example with Angular 2.0 including routing, components, ES6 etc have a look at this [post](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/05/14/creating-your-first-real-world-angular-2-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api-and-everything-in-between/?utm_content=buffer4f352&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer).

[Angular.io](https://angular.io/) is the official site for Angular 2.0. Recently Angular 2,0 moved to developer preview from alpha release. So it is a good time to start exploring Angular 2.0